# What am i doing wrong in this collision detection?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, collision-detection

I'm still a beginner in JavaScript , I spent the whole night reading about collision detection between two circles and I came up with the following.

You find the distance of the ball with this formule:

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y - y2, 2));
```

then you If the sum of the radii is greater than or equal to distance, the circles are colliding , i tried to make that in my code but it doesn't seem to work for me. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var x2 = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height - 20;
var y2 = 20;
var ballRadius = 20;
var ballRadius2 = 20;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var dx2 = 2;
var dy2 = 2;
var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y - y2, 2));

function drawBall() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawBall2() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x2, y2, ballRadius2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  drawBall();
  drawBall2();
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  x2 += dx2;
  y2 += dy2
  if (x && x2 > canvas.width - ballRadius || x && x2 < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
    dx2 = -dx2;
  }
  if (y && y2 > canvas.height - ballRadius || y && y2 < 0) {
    dy = -dy;
    dy2 = -dy2;
  }
  if (ballRadius + ballRadius2 >= distance) {
    alert("collision");
  }

}
setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
```

I want to know what I'm doing wrong with the calculations.

Comment: Please ellaborate on "doesn't seem to work".  Please be as specific as possible.  What have you tried?  What debugging steps have you taken?  What is supposed to happen?  What **is** happening?  Are the circles supposed to change color when they collide?  Do they do that?  Does one change color but the other doesn't?  Please add as much detail to your question as you can to the point of exhaustion so that we understand what you are doing, what you have tried, and what isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation itself is fine - the problem is that you're calculating the distance between your two balls just **once** before you even start the interval. The distance needs to be recalculated **continuously** inside your setinterval's callback function. Otherwise you're just comparing to a fixed number - which is the distance between the two balls at startup.

Here's an example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var x2 = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height - 20;
var y2 = 20;
var ballRadius = 20;
var ballRadius2 = 20;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var dx2 = 2;
var dy2 = 2;
var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y - y2, 2));

function drawBall() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawBall2() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x2, y2, ballRadius2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  drawBall();
  drawBall2();
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  x2 += dx2;
  y2 += dy2
  if (x && x2 > canvas.width - ballRadius || x && x2 < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
    dx2 = -dx2;
  }
  if (y && y2 > canvas.height - ballRadius || y && y2 < 0) {
    dy = -dy;
    dy2 = -dy2;
  }
  distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y - y2, 2));
  if (ballRadius + ballRadius2 >= distance) {
    console.log("collision");
  }

}
setInterval(draw, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="canv"></canvas>
```

Comment: No problem - glad I could help. =)